# Django - Table is not creating after migration

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms, digital-ocean, django-migrations

I want to add new functionality to my Django project on DigitalOcean server using Postgres database. The problem is that, everything works finely on local server, but on production server new table for new model is not creating. I've deleted all migration files, made migrations again, but again can't see new table on database. Please, help me to fix that problem. My exact error:

`relation "documents_app_employee" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "documents_app_employee" ("fin", "name", "surnam...`

Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    fin = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.surname
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateEmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=False):
        employee = super(CreateEmployeeForm, self).save(commit=False)
        Employee.objects.create(
            fin = employee.fin,
            name = employee.name,
            surname = employee.surname,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

scripts for deleting and undo migration:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
pip3 uninstall django
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

But again getting:

```
ProgrammingError at /employee_document

relation "documents_app_employee" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "documents_app_employee" ("fin", "name", "surnam...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem while migrating database while hosting on pythonanywhere. After a lot different methods including deleting and undoing migrations and redoing it again.

Then I finally used the default **db.sqlite3** database and exported the SQL from it (using sqlite3 browser) and converted it to a Postgresql using an online [sql converter](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-sql-to-postgres-online) and connected my project on **localhost postgres database** where **the tables were created using the obtained sql query** in **pgadmin** .

Then it worked fine when pushing it to production.

**sorry if my answer is not that clear I am new to stackoverflow as an user and not just as a browser. I will edit/comment my answer as per any doubts.*

Comment: I understood you, bro, but you know, I have very important datas in my Postgres on server. Thank you for help !

Comment: so use sql dump to extract queries for the data and after the procedure above again
then use those queries of data to re-enter in your database

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this issue and I fixed it by run `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` inside the container, you can change the python manage.py command in the Dockerfile and add `--run-syncdb` to it.

Hope this helps!